# Handling RxJava2 Observable inside an Android service

Tags: android, service, widget, rx-java2, paper-android

### Generalities:

I have an android widget that must be updated even if the app is killed. So I have an android service to handle this job.

The widget ui is update if data in the database is updated. This data may updated by other triggers. I mapped the widget ui update with an Observable from the database value.

The database is Paper https://github.com/pilgr/Paper, and I handle it with it RxJava2 wrapper https://github.com/pakoito/RxPaper2.

### Code :

Here is a simplified code for the service.

```
public class WidgetService extends Service {

    private CompositeDisposable mCompositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    private WidgetMager mWidgetManager = new WidgetManager();

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        reactOnNotification();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        AppLog.v(this, "Destroy service.");
        clearSubscriptions();
    }


    private void reactOnNotification() {
        mCompositeDisposable.add(
                RxPaperBook
                        .with("RT")
                        .observe("SINGLE", RTAQI.class, BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
                        .toObservable()
                        .doOnNext(value -> mWidgetManager.update(value))
                        .subscribeWith(new GenericSubscriber2<>("Notif"))
        );


        mCompositeDisposable.add(
                Observable
                        .interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .map(aLong -> (RTAQI) Paper.book("RT").read("SINGLE"))
                        .doOnNext(value -> mWidgetManager.update(value))
                        .subscribeWith(new GenericSubscriber2<>("Pulling"))

        );
    }

    private void clearSubscriptions() {
        if (mCompositeDisposable != null) {
            mCompositeDisposable.clear();
        }
        mCompositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    }
}
```

The widgetManager update the widget with the remote views.

### Problem :

For the example, I just put 2 widget update mechanisms :

- 1 by pulling every 1 sec (that works but is not clean and efficient) with Paper
- 1 by Rx Stream that intent to be efficient with RxPaper2 but doesn't work. The observable is not triggered. (Such Observable work fine in an app with mainTread)

I expect a problem of subscribeOn, I don t know really how to deal with this inside a Service. Any help is welcome.

Comment: try to log the result, add observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) before the update line